# why rsync doesn't seem to push the commit of a repo?

Tags: git, rsync

I have setup that I have to rsync my work to office computer,

```
rsync -arv --progress /Users/caistro/Development/project_repo/* ciastro@office:/home/caistro/code/git/project_repo
```

even though I commit locally, and as I have **project_repo/*** it doesn't rsync the commit or the whole **.git** folder ?

Comment: It may depend on your shell, but I know that `bash` doesn't include files and directories starting with `.` when using the `*` glob pattern.  So you would need an additional `/Users/caistro/Development/project_repo/.*` as input (`.*` instead of `*`).

Comment: thats correct thanks

Comment: @0x5453
Looks like its copying the same files from inside of the `project_repo` at the source to outside of `project_repo` directory in `git/` of destination location !

Comment: Why not rsync directories instead of files? `rsync -ahPv --del /Users/caistro/Development/project_repo caistro@office:/home/caistro/code/git/`